# Gradle Plugin Test UpToDateWhen method

Tags: gradle

I'm writing a gradle plugin that defines an `upToDateWhen` closure to skip the task when certain criteria is met.  I'm having trouble figuring out how to wrap a test around this method.  Currently it looks like:

```
class MyCoolTask extends DefaultTask {

  MyCoolTask() {
    outputs.upToDateWhen {
      if (somecondition)
        return true
      else
        return false
    }
  }
}
```

My test looks like this:

```
class MyCoolTaskTest {

  @Test
  void testUpToDateCheck() {
    project = ProjectBuilder.builder().build()
    project.apply plugin: 'myCoolPlugin'

    project.myCoolTask.execute()

    // But then how do you do a subsequent run and ensure that the task did not execute?

    project.myCoolTask.execute() // running this a second time does not work.

    project.myCoolTask.outputs.upToDateWhen() // Throws a syntax error
  }
}
```

Any insight that could be offered would be great!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ProjectBuilder` is meant for low-level tests that configure the build but don't execute any tasks. You can either factor out the contents of `outputs.upToDateWhen { ... }` into a method/class and test that, and/or write an acceptance test that executes a real build using the Gradle tooling API.